# if $m + n \geq 200$ then prove that $m \geq 100$ or $n \geq 100$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

This is a $m + n \geq 200 \implies (m \geq 100)\lor(n \geq 100)$ argument, so my approach was to use contraposition so it is:

$(m < 100)\land(n < 100)\implies m+n<200$

Then, my unexperienced self with proofs (yet) decided to use some values and substitute for the greatest possible values for $n$ and $m$ which are supposedly $199$ if the domain is integers or $199.9999999$ if it isn't (I really was experimenting with the question as it had not assumed a domain) and said that since the sums of the two biggest values of $n$ and $m$ is in fact less than 200, then my contrapositive argument is true and therefore the main argument is also true.
My proof was written in a sloppy manner because I didn't know how to formulate it but this is exactly how I solved it.

Is this correct? If it isn't, then how should it have been done? (or even if it is, I am sure there is a more systematic approach to it, I'd be happy to know what it is)

Comment: If $m+n\geq 200$ then prove that $m\geq 100~~\color{red}{\text{AND}}~~n\geq 100$... What can you say about $300+50$? (*You can make the statement true by changing the word "and" to something else*)

Comment: As for a proof for the statement $m+n\geq 200\implies m\geq 100\vee n\geq 100$, then instead of using specific values of $m$ and $n$ to try to prove $(m<100)\wedge (n<100)\implies m+n<200$, you need to be incredibly generic and use only the properties $m<100$ and $n<100$ and not use anything more specific than that about $n$ and $m$.  Use the properties of addition and the less-than relation.  You should know $a<b\implies a+c<b+c$.  Use that property twice to get $m+n<100+n<100+100$ and then use transitivity to get $m+n<200$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you have switched around the "and"s and "or"s, the contraposed statement is easy to prove:

Assume $m<100$ and $n<100$. Then

$$ m+n < 100+n = n+100 < 100+100 = 200 $$

because $a<b \Rightarrow a+c<b+c$ which is a quite basic property of $<$.

Comment: I haven't thought of this and this far more elegant than I would have ever written it. But, is my answer considered wrong? I kind of wrote it in a Discrete Maths 1 course exam so.

Comment: @EyadH: Your concrete upper bounds are wrong -- if $m$ and $n$ are integers, then their sum cannot be more than $198$; if the are arbitrary real numbers, then the sum can be anything that is less than $200$, such as $199.99999995$ which is larger than the "largest value" you're proposing More seriously, you're just _asserting_ that those are the largest possible values. At the level of detail you're working with, for a proof you're supposed to explain _how you know that_..

Comment: I think you misunderstood, the numbers in the questions were not the numbers specifically used or made to be the largest values. What I did in the exam paper however was just add two numbers that are very close to 100 but not quite 100 and assert that as long as both $n$ and $m$ are less than 100 each, then both will always have a sum less than 200.

Comment: @EyadH. Even so, your task is to prove it *for* **all** values, not just those values close to the boundary.  Of course, it sounds silly to say, but *what if* we took values that were much smaller than $100$ for each of $m$ and $n$, what is to stop them from "wrapping around" and somehow ending up with their sum larger than $200$?  We know that this can't happen, but we have to be able to successfully explain why.  Just showing it is true for a specific pair is very different than showing it is true *for all pairs*.